# How do take the value from a combobox and use it to run an SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to take the value from a combo box (in this case 'cboFullName' located on form 'frmMasterNotebook') and cross reference it to table 'tblSearchEngine01' so that an update gets made to column 'query05contactselect' for all records where in column 'contact' the value matches to that selected by the combobox ('cboFullName').   Below is my code but I am getting a syntax error message.

```
Private Sub cboFullName_AfterUpdate()

 st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01, SET tblSearchEngine01.Query05ContactSelect = '1' WHERE (((tblSearchEngine01.[contact])=([forms]![frmmasternotebook]![cbofullname]))))"
            Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

Comment: You'd probably want the combobox_onchange() event

Comment: Thanks Ckuhn but what comes next? A query linked to the combobox? And how do i link it to the id?

Comment: This is a really broad question, and probably off topic for SO. There are a few ways to do it. Personally, I like using an unbound combo box and the Form's `filter` property.

Comment: Sorry Chuck, I am a bit of a beginner. I Just want to be able to capture the value that the combobox displays and bring that value into a table behind the scenes so i can use it in a query.

Comment: No reason to store it in a table. I suggest researching the problem further. I've given you enough to get started. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code builds an `UPDATE` statement which includes a comma after the table name ...

```
UPDATE tblSearchEngine01, SET
                        ^
```

Remove that comma and see whether Access complains about anything else.

However I suggest you start by creating and testing a new query in Access' query designer.  Paste this statement into SQL View of your new query ...

```
UPDATE tblSearchEngine01
SET Query05ContactSelect = '1'
WHERE [contact] = [forms]![frmmasternotebook]![cbofullname];
```

After you revise and test the statement so that Access executes it without complaint, then you can revise your VBA code to produce the exact same statement text which works in the query designer.

Comment: I also suggest you consider using `DAO.Database` `Execute` method instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL` to execute your `UPDATE`.  This difference doesn't contribute to your present problem, but `Execute` with the `dbFailonerror` option is generally the better way to go.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Prior to your answer i found a way to do it using DAO.Recordset (which i pasted as an additional answer).  Is that what you were referring to in your last comment?

Comment: No, look in the Access help system at the topic titled "Database.Execute Method".  That is a different way to execute your `UPDATE` statement (instead of using `DoCmd.RunSQL`).

Answer (score 1):

Using DAO this is another way to resolve my issue:

```
Private Sub cboFullName_AfterUpdate()


Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSearchEngine06", dbOpenTable)
rst.AddNew
rst!Contact = Me.cboFullName.Text
rst!ContactID = Me.cboFullName
rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```